# 'Trying to open unclosed connection' error' using Mongoose and embedded documents

Tags: connection, mongoose, runtime-error

I'm getting a connection related error when defining a static query that filters an embedded document field.
I've tried to separate the embedded document in a separate schema file but didn't resolve the issue. Any ideas?

Error follows:

```
C:\development_GIT\myproject\app\models\mymodel.js:40
    this.find({ text.lang_code: langCode }).sort('text.name').exec(callback);
                        ^

Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.open (C:\development_GIT\myproject\node_
modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:205:15)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\development_GIT\myproject\node_modules\mongoose
\lib\index.js:156:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\development_GIT\myproject\server.js:13:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:1
```

The error is launched when using the filter `{ text.lang_code: langCode }`
 option in the following model. If I don't use the embedded document and try to filter for exampe `{ _id: langCode }` it does not throw errors.

```
    //MyModel.js located at ./app/models

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;



     var MyModelSchema = new Schema({
      name: { type: String, trim: true },
      text: [{ name: String, lang_code: String }]

    });


    MyModelSchema .static({


      findByLangCode : function(langCode, callback) {

        this.find({ text.lang_code: langCode }).sort('text.name').exec(callback);

      }

    });

mongoose.model('MyModel', CategorySchema);
```

The first lines of my main file server.js are:

```
//server.js
var express = require('express');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config = require('./config/config')[env];
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
require('express-namespace');

mongoose.connect(config.db);

// Bootstrap models
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/app/models').forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) require(__dirname + '/app/models/' + file)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was building the query in a different way. It seems that subdocuments can not be used inside find().

```
Before: (not working)
this.find({ text.lang_code: langCode }).sort('text.name').exec(callback);

After (working)

this.find().where('text.lang_code').equals(langCode).sort('text.name').exec(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this all the time and it works fine for me.

`this.find({ 'text.lang_code': langCode }).sort('text.name').exec(callback);`

MongoDb can only handle one lvl of objects, but if you give it a string like you are doing in the .where function, mongodb will do magic and match it to subdocuments :)

Comment: thanks for tour comment. It is great to know that in certain conditions it works as expected. Maybe the difference between my code and yours is how the connection is managed...